# String becomes undefined in mapReduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to count the number of docs per day in my collection. I am using mongoDB mapReduce function with the following map and reduce functions:

```
var tsMapper = function(){
    // Get the timestamp and convert it to Date
    var ts = new Date((this.ntimestamp_ms));
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var year = ts.getFullYear();
    var month = months[ts.getMonth()];
    var date = ts.getDate();
    var newTS = month + ' ' + date + ' ' + year;
    // emit the newTS and value as 1
    emit(String(newTS), 1);
   }
```

and the Reducer function:

```
var reducer = function(key,values){
    return Array.sum(values);
    }
```

Then when I run the code on my database:

```
db.test.mapReduce(tsMapper, reducer, {"out" : "ts_count"})
```

it only returns a collection with one document in it with the "_id" of "undefined NaN NaN" and the value equal to the total number of documents:

```
{ "_id" : "undefined NaN NaN", "value" : 6 }
```

Could somebody please let me know why the newTS String is becoming "undefined NaN NaN"?

Comment: Where are you running your reducer function? Where are the docs you're pulling in? I think we need a little more code if you have it .

Comment: I am running the code inside the mongo shell. The docs are in a mongoDB database.